# Tkinter - event that triggers after a window has maximized

Tags: python, tkinter, python-turtle

In turtle, I am interested in finding out the canvas dimensions once my main window has "maximized".

The code for creating and maximizing a turtle window is:

```py
def make_window2():
    canvas = t.getcanvas()
    root = canvas.winfo_toplevel()    
    root.title("Serpenski")
    root.state('zoomed')
    return root, canvas, t
```

where `t` is the imported `turtle` object (i.e `import turtle as t`)

Issue happens when I try to use it.

```py
window, canvas, turtle = make_window2()
screen = turtle.Screen()
win_width = screen.window_width()
win_height = screen.window_height()
print((win_width, win_height))
time.sleep(10) #waiting 10 seconds
win_width = screen.window_width()
win_height = screen.window_height()
print((win_width, win_height)) # Prints the same thing as before...
```

I ran my script in the interpreter mode (passing `-i` switch to python binary). During `time.sleep(10)`, if you happen to see turtle window, you'd see that the resize operation is in progress and it hangs until the next interpreter prompt is shown (i.e. when the above bit of code completes executing). Please note, that the resize operation completes after this code execution is over.

So how to run the above code after the root window has maximized?

PS: using python 3.10.2, on windows 11 machine.

Comment: `time.sleep()` does not allow anything to actually happen; it just wastes time.  I think `window.update_idletasks()` is the minimum thing you could do that would allow the window to start reporting its new dimensions after the state change.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is a soluiton. After some hacking around, I found that `turtle.reset()` does the trick.